# PostgreSQL nondeterministic collations are not supported for LIKE

Tags: collation, unicode, postgresql-12, case-sensitive, international-components-unicode

I am using Postgresql v12.
I created a collation like this:

```
CREATE COLLATION ci (provider = icu, locale = 'tr_TR', deterministic = false);
```

I used that collation in a table:

```
create table testtable1 (
    id serial  primary key,
    name text  COLLATE "ci"
);
```

And I inserted sample data:

```
insert into testtable1 values(3,'abc');
```

When I query that table using `LIKE`, it returns the following error:

```
select name from testtable1 WHERE name LIKE '%a%'
```

> ERROR:  nondeterministic collations are not supported for LIKE
>   SQL state: 0A000

But I need to use `LIKE`. Is there any way to allow this?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/collation.html says "While nondeterministic collations give a more “correct” behavior, especially when considering the full power of Unicode and its many special cases, they also have some drawbacks. Foremost, their use leads to a performance penalty. Also, certain operations are not possible with nondeterministic collations, such as pattern matching operations. Therefore, they should be used only in cases where they are specifically wanted.": I understand that to use LIKE you need a deterministic collation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that most of the time the custom, non-deterministic collation works for you and you only need something deterministic occasionally, then you can simply provide the deterministic collation when needed via the `COLLATE` clause. For example, in your case, you can use the `tr-TR-x-icu` collation as follows:

```sql
select name from testtable1 WHERE name LIKE '%a%' COLLATE "tr-TR-x-icu"
```

You can see a working demo of this, using your sample code posted in the question, on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=32015f5462a8b91079ac8db827acf9c3).

Of course, that will be case-sensitive. For this you need to use the `ILIKE` operator which is case-*in*sensitive. For example:

```sql
select name from testtable1 WHERE name ILIKE '%A%' COLLATE "tr-TR-x-icu"
```

But, the `=` operator is still case-sensitive because the collation as defined in the `CREATE COLLATION` statement did not alter the default sensitivities, and by default collations are everything-sensitive (which is [*not* the same as binary collations](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/07/13/no-binary-collations-are-not-case-sensitive/), just FYI).

To create a collation that uses the "tr-TR" locale *and* is also case-*in*sensitive, you need to specify the `locale` property in the `CREATE COLLATION` statement as follows:

```sql
locale = 'tr-TR-u-ks-level2'
```

To see that in action, please see: [db<>fiddle example 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0dc7724009b6f09ae193375a56799a4c)

Please see "[Unicode Technical Standard #35: UNICODE LOCALE DATA MARKUP LANGUAGE (LDML), PART 5: COLLATION](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-collation.html#Setting_Options)" for the full list of collation options.

And, please visit [Collations Info](https://collations.info/) for collation-related info. It's geared mostly towards SQL Server and .NET, but has some MySQL and PostgreSQL stuff, and the key concepts are generally the same across platforms and languages.

Comment: I tried your code but error message is the same.

Comment: @BanuAkkus Did you look at the working demo on db<>fiddle? What _exactly_ did you try?

Comment: I looked your demo on db<>fiddle. I changed my query as "select name from testtable1 WHERE name LIKE '%a%' COLLATE "tr-TR-x-icu" Error message is the same.

Comment: @BanuAkkus Is that the only query running? Is that the entire query or is there another `LIKE` clause? The `COLLATE` clause is per each predicate / condition.

Comment: Yes, there is only one query. I am testing on test environment. If I solve "LIKE" issue, I will use on production.

Comment: @BanuAkkus What does the following query return: `select collisdeterministic from pg_collation where collname = 'tr-TR-x-icu'` ?

Comment: It returns "true"

Comment: Is there anything else should I do? @solomon-rutzky

Comment: @BanuAkkus I'm not sure. I don't have any other PostgreSQL v12 to play with other than what's on db<>fiddle. I'm not a PostgreSQL expert. I know quite a bit about collations, but I mostly work with SQL Server so I'm not as familiar with the nuances of other RDBMSs. All I know is that I reproduced the error on db<>fiddle using your example code, then did what I thought might work and it appeared to work. If it doesn't work on your system, perhaps your column is using a different encoding, or maybe there is a different setting at the DB, server, or connection levels?

Comment: I tested on Amazon RDS postgresql instance v12 it worked fine. But it does not compare properly. select name from testtable1 WHERE name LIKE '%a%' COLLATE "tr-TR-x-icu" works fine and return result but LIKE '%A%'  returns nothing.

Comment: please check on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9b382be48e5c62692f352e550290555c

Comment: @BanuAkkus For that, at minimum you could simply use `ILIKE` for case-insensitivity (example here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=63d489f9406b3c5ab7b831596959626b). But I am looking to see if there is another way that would also work with the `=` operator without needing to use `COLLATE` there as well.

Comment: "=" operator works fine but we need use "like" queries sometimes. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @BanuAkkus But in the current configuration, the `=` operator is _not_ case-*in*sensitive. Isn't that what you are looking for? Meaning, the following example shows that `WHERE name = 'aBc'` does not return any rows. Should it? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=72ef317adfb60b019c7682b632fb2617

Comment: of course it should return something. I got your point now. What should I do?

Comment: @BanuAkkus I figured out how to create the case-insensitive collation. I have updated my answer which includes a link to a db<>fiddle example showing it working and includes explanations.

Comment: Awesome, thanks !